# Change the color of a pixel on a surface from a thread pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pygame, multiprocessing

I'm working on a voxel raytracer in Python, just ported from Tkinter to Pygame for window management and pixel drawing. I use a thread pool to do the raytracing for each pixel, in my original code the `trace` function does various calculations before returning the color as a hex string: The main loop runs periodically on the main thread (eg: 30 times a second for 30 FPS) and calls the pool with a range to request new traces and update all pixel colors, each index is translated to a 2D position to know which location each color refers to. I left out functions unrelated to my question in this simplified example, like how I'm converting index `i` to two `x, y` integer positions in a custom vector class, same as the hex to `r, g, b` converter... and yes I have a way to break out of the `while True` loop when quitting, the representation below runs just as intended.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pygame as pg

def trace(i):
    # Rays are calculated here, for simplicity of example return a fixed color
    return "ff7f00"

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((64, 16))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
pool = mp.Pool()
while True:
    # Raytrace each pixel and draw the new color, 64 * 16 = 1024
    result = pool.map(trace, range(0, 1024)):
    for i, c in enumerate(result):
        pos = vec2_from_index(i)
        col = rgb_from_hex(c)
        screen.set_at((pos.x, pos.y), (col.r, col.g, col.b))
    clock.tick(30)
```

But there's a problem: Performance is very slow on the main thread which acts as a bottleneck, the tracing threads don't even get to run at their full potential because of this. At higher resolutions there are a lot more pixels, eg: 240 x 120 = 28800 entries in the `result` array; Merely fetching it without doing anything to the result saddles the main thread, enumerating the result to apply the colors makes it even worse. I'm hoping to remove this burden by changing the pixel being traced directly on the thread calculating it, instead of the helper thread merely returning the 6-character hex string and the main thread having to process it. The ideal code would then look something like this instead:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((64, 16))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
pool = mp.Pool()
def trace(i):
    # Rays are calculated here, for simplicity of example return a fixed color
    pos = vec2_from_index(i)
    col = rgb_from_hex("ff7f00")
    screen.set_at((pos.x, pos.y), (col.r, col.g, col.b))

while True:
    # Raytrace each pixel and draw the new color, 64 * 16 = 1024
    pool.map(trace, range(0, 1024)):
    clock.tick(30)
```

However this approach is bound to fail due to the way threading works: Threads can only return a modified result when the function ends, they can't edit variables from the outside directly in a way that will be seen by the main thread or other threads. Any changes done by the process are thus temporary and only exist in the reality of this thread before it finishes.

What do you see as the best solution here, in case anything better than my current approach is possible? Is there a way for threads to execute `pygame.set_at` on the screen surface with permanent results? Also in this case I wouldn't need the thread pool to return a result... should I use something other than `pool.map` for more efficiency?

Comment: Why do you want to change the color of the pixel direct in the thread? Add the information in a queue (position and color). Process the information in the queue in the main thread. Then it doesn't matter how slow the main thread is. Anyway, python and pygame is way too slow for raytracing. For this reason I have given up my own attempt: https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameRayTracing

Comment: That's close to what I'm doing now, though it's not really a queue as all pixels are updated at once to avoid tearing: It's still slow as having the main thread handle so many results is a bottleneck no matter how I do it, hence I'd rather have threads doing that too. One solution is for each thread to return an unique surface which I then `blit` onto the main screen in the main thread, I'll try tiling it like that. And yes it's very slow especially on CPU, it only works as my design is meant to work at small resolutions and emulate Doom era graphics which is tolerable (eg: 120 x 60 @ 24 FPS).

Comment: https://github.com/MirceaKitsune/python_raytracer This is my project so far, I just implemented mouse support last night with a few other improvements. At the current default resolution of 96 x 64 @ 24 FPS with a draw distance of 192 voxels, I get a stable 10 FPS which is just tolerable. I use a lot of optimizations to get there, such as storing each voxel in a list and getting its 3D position from the array index... I don't use models just points in floating space which the ray checks at integer positions as it moves around, each material can have its own function that affects the light ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the perfect solution and would be happy to share it here as well! I will modify my initial example to show what I did roughly.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pygame as pg
import math

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((64, 16))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
pool = mp.Pool()
threads = mp.cpu_count()

def draw_trace(i):
    # Rays are calculated here, for simplicity of example return a fixed color
    return rgb(255, 127, 0)

def draw(thread):
    # Create a new surface and draw every pixel on it
    srf = pg.Surface((64, math.ceil(16 / threads)))
    for i in range(64 * math.ceil(16 / threads)):
        pos = vec2_from_index(i)
        col = draw_trace(i)
        srf.set_at((pos.x, pos.y), (col.r, col.g, col.b))
    return pg.image.tobytes(srf, "RGB")

while True:
    # Raytrace each pixel and draw the new color, 64 * 16 = 1024
    result = pool.map(draw, range(0, 1024)):
    for i, s in enumerate(result):
        srf = pg.image.frombytes(s, (64, math.ceil(16 / threads)), "RGB")
        screen.blit(srf, (0, math.ceil(16 / threads) * i))
    clock.tick(30)
```

This achieves exactly what I want, with one thread always working on its own vertical slice: Each thread creates its own surface and draws the pixels to it after obtaining their colors. This surface is then packed using `tobytes`, send to the main thread by the thread pool, and unpacked with `frombytes`... not doing this causes an error about something called "pickling" which I don't fully understand. The main thread then calculates which vertical tile belongs where and blits it to the main canvas to update it.

The performance improvement is very palpable: The pygame clock reports over 15 FPS where I previously had 10, in practice it feels like it's twice faster at least! This is likely the last major performance improvement I'll achieve architecturally but definitely makes the whole project even more usable. If anyone's interested in checking it out you can find my project on Github which now contains this solution:

https://github.com/MirceaKitsune/python_raytracer